# Connect application from android emulator to network

Tags: android

I'm working in Mac OS. I'm developing a script to test the functionalities of an Android application. But in the company in which I work, they use a proxy

In Android Studio emulator I set the proxy in `Mobile Settings`, So the network navigation works well.

After my research, I found in the Android documentation that I have to do a port forwarding (doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

I followed the instructions - but it does not work.
I do not know if there is a step I'm doing wrong. I'm using CNTLM to redirect the requests in my OS

I have doubts about this step:

`redir add tcp:5000:6000`

I'm not sure I'm using the right port. Should I designate specific ports?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> tcp:5000:6000

try

> tcp:6000:5000

but also make sure to change the port in your client.java and server.java too.

Comment: first thank you for your answer, and sorry for my late response
so if I understand correctly I have to change my java code, can't I just add a specific configuration to my emulator?
in the company in which I work, the android application is extarnalized. and they preferred that I do not change the project code
when I look at my logcat of my emulator i have this error :                                    
Failed to connect to server: java.io.IOException: Failed to authenticate with proxy

Comment: The connection was accepted by TCP, to the proxy, which then failed your authentication. For authentication, use java.net.Authenticator to set proxy's configuration and set the system properties http.proxyUser and http.proxyPassword. The properties "http.proxyUser" and "http.proxyPassword" are not obligatory.